# Matching number as string at beginning of string while passing variable in python

Tags: python, regex

Stupid question, but I am at a loss for trying! I am trying to find matches in array with this number, passed as string, but only from the start of the other string.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do. In the comment section I am trying to pass the query string as a variable, but not sure how to do this.

Below this the query is manually added and should print True for `array[1]` but I am getting no positive result. The number should only match strings where they match at the beginning followed by any other combinations of 1's and 2's.

```
t1 = "112"

array = [['121121'], ['1121211']]

#for item in array:
#    if re.search(r'^t1.', str(item)):
#        print(item)
#        print(True)

for item in array:
    if re.search(r'^112.', str(item)):
        print(item)
        print(True)
```

Comment: Because you type-cast the list to a string. Use `if re.search(r'^112.', item[0]):` Also, your regex must be `r'^112[12]*$'` to match strings that start with `112` and then can contain any amount of `1` or `2` chars.

Comment: Ah, perfect! And how going about passing the `t1` variable?

Comment: Use string concatenation to build up the re that you want: `'^' + t1`

Comment: But -- why use re at all? Strings have a `startswith` method

Comment: @JohnColeman, that is the simplest option

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah that is much easier... Have to stop overthinking simple solutions!

Comment: If you need to validate the rest of the string, you can use a regex. Although there are other ways here as well. Also, see my [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224618/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that you type-cast the list to a string. You need `re.search(r'^112.', item[0]):` or similar to get to the first list item string.

Also, `.` matches any char but a line break char, but you mention "*The number should only match strings where they match at the beginning followed by any other combinations of 1's and 2's.*", so the `.` must be replaced with `[12]*`. Together with `re.fullmatch`, this will fix the issue.

You can use

```py
import re
t1 = "112"
array = [['121121'], ['1121211']]
for item in array:
    if item and re.fullmatch(fr'{t1}[12]*', item[0]):
        print(True,'->', item)
    else:
        print(False,'->', item)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZbjhoJ). Output:

```
False -> ['121121']
True -> ['1121211']
```

NOTES:

- `fr'{t1}[12]*'` builds the regex dynamically by passing `t1` to the pattern, and
- `re.fullmatch` allows entire string match only.
- `if item:` makes sure the regex is run only on non-empty `item`s.

A non-regex approach:

```py
t1 = "112"
array = [['121121'], ['1121211'], ['112223']]
for item in array:
    if item and item[0].startswith(t1) and all(x in ['1','2'] for x in item[0]):
        print(True,'->', item)
    else:
        print(False,'->', item)
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZyvT1k).

Comment: I am accepting this answer, it best answers my question! However I have to give a shoutout to @JohnColeman's answer, very simple, but as mentioned by Wiktor Stribizew, does not address the post 1's and 2's.

Comment: @roelofco I added the non-regex approach at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`array` is a nested list, so `item` is equal to `['121121']` on the first iteration and `['1121211']` on the second.

You probably meant to declare array as `array = ['121121','1121211']`:

```py
t1 = "112"

array = ['121121','1121211']

#for item in array:
#    if re.search(r'^t1.', str(item)):
#        print(item)
#        print(True)

for item in array:
    if re.search(r'^112.', str(item)):
        print(item)
        print(True)
```

I get the following output:

```
1121211
True
```

Passing a variable is simple:

```py
t1 = "112"

array = ['121121','1121211']

for item in array:
    if re.search(f'^{t1}', str(item)):
        print(item)
        print(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution here is to ditch `re` and use the `startswith` string method:

```
[row[0].startswith(t1) for row in array]
```

evaluates to

```
[False, True]
```

Comment: But OP says "*The number should only match strings where they match at the beginning followed by any other combinations of 1's and 2's.*" You cannot just use a mere `.startswith` here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point, but OP's re pattern didn't try to enforce any condition on the rest of the string. I took it to be implicit in the problem statement that the strings in question were in the alphabet `{1,2}`. You are of course correct that a full-fledged `re` approach would be needed to validate such assumptions. (+1 for your nice answer showing how).

Comment: I see. Anyway, I added [both approaches in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224618/3832970).